# I'm replacing old dishwasher but the connectors are different

Tags: dishwasher

[image]

Ok so the white is the piece comming out of dishwasher and other copper one is comming from water supply under sink. How do I connect the two together  when the white is threaded and two big to fit the copper fitting. I don't want to have to replace the copper line it's a older house and would require having to do do much.  I'm doing this on my own and I'm a girl but not stupid but am limited in tools and so need a easy fix thank you mary[image][image][image][image: enter image description here] pop(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWxVx.jpg)![enter image description here][image]

Comment: I'm not able to make out the water supply part of the image.

Comment: Am I supposed to concentrate on the blurry part of the image or the focused part? Why are all three images the same?

Comment: I'm new at this hold on will correct it

Comment: I'm going to take better pictures and and try to explain so please hold on a second ty

Comment: No problem. Just want to give your question a fair chance at being answered.

Comment: The last picture shows the piece that was on the other dishwasher and the water line the metal bracket was connect to the intake by 4 screws nothing was threaded together do you get what I mean

Comment: Did the dishwasher come with any fittings? There might be one that will make it easier to connect to your existing copper water line. That last picture you posted looks like you removed part of the old dishwasher. You may have to spend a few dollars on a tubing cutter to get a nice clean cut on the old copper tubing.

Comment: No it's a used one just came with drain hose witch is a different size

Answer (score 6):

It is in your interest to understand / measure the connectors on the dishwasher and your water supply to select the right hose adapter.

Perhaps one of these lines will allow you to bridge the new dishwasher into the existing water lines;

[https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dishwasher+line](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dishwasher%20line)

If you are near a Home Depot or Lowe's try their websites as well.  Let us know when you are successful!

Best to minimize the number of parts: you may need an adapter to bridge your hose into the female copper piping fitting.

[image]

Whirlpool W10685193 Dishwasher Swivel Gooseneck Fitting. **3/4 by 3/8-Inch**

Or get a flexible 3/8" steel braided supply line, that is however long you need, and then you don't have to mess with copper. Just make sure the other end will fit on the valve under the sink (e.g., you might need a 3/8" to 1/2"). The fitting pictured usually comes in the bag with 10' supply lines along with other adapters you might need.

Comment: Thank you I live right behind home Depot I'm one one there favorite customers been redoing whole inside of my house myself put in new wood flooring and that was a project  but turned out nice. Thank you for your help heading to home depot

Comment: @MaryWard Bring the pictures of your project: sometimes they have older / experienced personnel that can help you to quickly find the part and offer alternative solutions.  Maybe post pictures of your successful install?

Comment: Replace the rubber hose gasket with a silicon gasket or, in time, it will start to leak.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're going to have to replace at least *some* of that copper line as it appears to have been cut off before the fitting!

In the (now removed) image of just the copper line against a white background, it looks like you've got an inline connector (SharkBite baggie) to repair that copper line, but the line has a dent in it near the threaded nipple. I'd suggest that you may want to discard that dented line.

Consider getting a new fitting to go on the line at the point where it was cut, then put a flexible line between that and the fitting on the dishwasher. This will allow you to get a fitting that goes on the dishwasher, then you can get the proper fitting for the brass line that will match whatever is on the other end of that flexible line.

If you can't find something for the brass end that will match up with your flexible line (pretty unlikely, I'd think) you may have to get an adapter for the brass end.

Comment: The copper line is what comes from the line under the sink so I was thinking I'd have to get something that fits around the where threaded piece that will join the brass fitting to it right or no

Answer (score 3):

Easy answer, buy a tubing cutter and a dishwasher install kit. Find a section of the existing tubing that's not bent and cut it with the tubing cutter so you get a nice clean round cut. You can google how to use a tubing cutter, they're also inexpensive. The install kit will have a brass compression fitting which will connect to the tubing you just cut (you'll need to wrenches to tighten it). There will be a fitting in the kit that you will screw on to the white fitting on the new dishwasher, careful don't break the white plastic fitting. The kit will have a flexible hose that will connect to the two fittings.

Edit:The fitting you connect to the copper tubing is an adapter which will allow you to connect the flexible hose to the copper tubing. The other fitting going to the dishwasher is also an adapter that will allow you to connect the flexible hose to the dishwasher. Now you can easily connect the flexible hose to each adapter fitting. This is much easier than trying to bend the copper tubing to connect it to the dishwasher.

Answer (score 1):

The connection between those two fittings is made using an appliance hose.

while these superficially look like garden hoses they are manufactured to a much higher quality because a leak indoors is much more serious than outdoors.

your brass fitting appears to be connected to a very beat up piece of copper tubing, that will need to be replaced before it can be reliably connected to your water supply.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you haven't missed an easy way. If the sink is nearby, look at the water pipes for the taps under the sink. If the water pipe there has joins (such as a local shut-off tap) then you may be able to buy a T-piece (not sure of local word). Then attach long flexible pipe. This way you might only need to screw and unscrew parts without special tools, and high chance of success. I wish you good luck, and invite you to continue consulting all of us.